# How to pass multiple objects or values in FlatList extraData

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a situation where I need to pass both State and Props in the FlatList extraData.

I tried something like this but **didn't** work.

```
 <FlatList
      numColumns={1}
      data={this.props.artists}
      renderItem={this.renderArtistItem}
      initialNumToRender={15}
      keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      extraData={(this.state, this.props.league)}
    />
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this:

```
<FlatList
  numColumns={1}
  data={this.props.artists}
  renderItem={this.renderArtistItem}
  initialNumToRender={15}
  keyExtractor={item => item.id}
  extraData={[this.state, this.props.league]}
/>
```

As it will work as an array in extra data.

Comment: Won't this force a re-render constantly even though state and props don't change? `var a = {}; [a] === [a]` is false.

Answer (score -1):

try this,

```
<FlatList
  numColumns={1}
  data={this.props.artists}
  renderItem={this.renderArtistItem}
  initialNumToRender={15}
  keyExtractor={item => item.id}
  extraData={{state:this.state, props:this.props.league}}
/>
```

Comment: That will not work because PureComponents makes a shallow comparison. In your example, both `state` and `props` object would be referring the same object all the time. Because of the shallow comparison, no changes inside `this.state` or `this.props` would be taken in account..

Comment: @mayid two objects are never shallow equal even if they have the same values (`({a: 1}) === ({a: 1}) => false` so this solution would force a re-render of the Flatlist on every render because it is constantly given a new object.

Comment: Hey @JacobLauritzen, of course two objects are always different, because of Identity. However, notice that "shallow equal" comparison doesn't involve Identity. It only compares the object properties. As FlatList is a PureComponent, objects in extraData will be used for shallow comparison. Maybe check this doc https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#extradata or react's PureComponent doc: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent

Comment: @mayid I was under the impression that props would be compared using shallow equal, not the properties of `extraData`. In that way, `extraData` is simply another prop which will be compared with itself. Some quick testing seems to confirm this.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
const extraData = {
      ...this.state,
      ...this.props
    };

<FlatList
 numColumns={1}
  data={this.props.artists}
  renderItem={this.renderArtistItem}
  initialNumToRender={15}
  keyExtractor={item => item.id}
  extraData={extraData}
/>
```

Comment: This solution is no different from simply passing an empty object like this: `extraData={{}}`. During each render a new empty object will be passed to extraData prop, causing the FlatList to re-render.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set state to extraData prop.

```
    <FlatList
       numColumns={1}
       data={this.props.artists}
       renderItem={this.renderArtistItem}
       initialNumToRender={15}
       keyExtractor={item => item.id}
       extraData={this.state}
    />
```